# Does WhatsApp have a golden key to decrypt messages?

Tags: encryption, instant-messaging, whatsapp

The head of Information and Communication Technologies Authority of Turkey said this on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/ofatihsayan/status/820372561485766656) yesterday:

> WhatsApp can read your end to end encrypted messages when necessary. It can decrypt your messages by using a golden key that stored in device memory.

Is there any evidence to this?

Comment: No, there is no evidence of that "golden key". It is more likely that this is just a made up or exaggerated story which might be useful in following a specific political agenda. Ask your source to provide evidence. But it is true that WhatsApp is closed source and might change the way it works at any time, similar to many other messaging apps. And it is true that there is currently a design issue discussed, see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148469/attack-vector-for-exploiting-whatsapps-retransmission-vulnerability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "golden key stored in device memory"? Not that I know of.

But WhatsApp does have a vulnerability that potentially allows it to access any messages not yet marked as delivered, according to [this Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/jan/13/whatsapp-backdoor-allows-snooping-on-encrypted-messages) from 13 January 2017:

> WhatsApp has the ability to force the generation of new encryption keys for offline users, unbeknown to the sender and recipient of the messages, and to make the sender re-encrypt messages with new keys and send them again for any messages that have not been marked as delivered.
>
> The recipient is not made aware of this change in encryption, while the sender is only notified if they have opted-in to encryption warnings in settings, and only after the messages have been re-sent. This re-encryption and rebroadcasting effectively allows WhatsApp to intercept and read users’ messages.
>
> The security loophole was discovered by Tobias Boelter, a cryptography and security researcher at the University of California, Berkeley. He told the Guardian: “If WhatsApp is asked by a government agency to disclose its messaging records, it can effectively grant access due to the change in keys.”
>
> The vulnerability is not inherent to the Signal protocol. Open Whisper Systems’ messaging app, Signal, the app used and recommended by whistleblower Edward Snowden, does not suffer from the same vulnerability.

This a *bit* like having a golden key for the conversation concerned, in that it could allow access to all future messages in that conversation, from the moment of the interception onwards:

> Boelter said: “[Some] might say that this vulnerability could only be abused to snoop on ‘single’ targeted messages, not entire conversations. This is not true if you consider that the WhatsApp server can just forward messages without sending the ‘message was received by recipient’ notification (or the double tick), which users might not notice. Using the retransmission vulnerability, the WhatsApp server can then later get a transcript of the whole conversation, not just a single message.”

Comment: I had a hard time to understand this and still have no success. As far as I understand: Alice sends a message to Bob but Bob is offline. Message reached to Whatsapp server but not Bob. At that point Whatsapp has an ability to force the generation of new encryption keys for **Bob**. But how can Whatsapp or any other third party read and intercept by re-encrypting and rebroadcating the message. Is the encryption process starts when message reaches the Whatsapp server? If so, how can it be end-to-end encryption? I'm a little lost as you can see, can you clear things a little for me?

Comment: "*As far as I understand: Alice sends a message to Bob but Bob is offline. Message reached to Whatsapp server but not Bob. At that point Whatsapp has an ability to force the generation of new encryption keys for **Bob**.*" Correct. And if WhatsApp *does* generate a new keypair that is Bob's, then Alice's WhatsApp client will re-encrypt her message, this time to the public key of that new key pair, and then re-transmit her message to the WhatsApp server. Since WhatsApp knows the private key, and has received the message, WhatsApp can read the message.

Comment: Additionally, I would *speculate* that the WhatsApp server can make Bob "offline" whenever it wants to, by just disconnecting him. If it does this briefly enough (e.g. just for the few milliseconds it would take the server to generate a new keypair), it would be unnoticeable. I *speculate further* that if it did this for both Alice and Bob, then - as it would know their private keys - it would be capable of a full-on [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), which isn't necessarily the same thing as having a golden key, but has many equivalences.

Comment: If you are down-voting this answer, please provide a comment to explain why. That's only helpful and polite. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's implausible that WhatsApp owns a key to read your end-to-end encrypted messages.

WhatsApp [implements end-to-end encryption](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030015) per the [Signal protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol) which has maintained a good reputation in the security community. From their [security whitepaper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf):

> WhatsApp messages, voice and video
>   calls between a sender and receiver that use WhatsApp client software
>   released after March 31, 2016 are end-to-end encrypted.
>
> The Signal Protocol, designed by Open Whisper Systems, is the basis for
>   WhatsApp’s end-to-end encryption. **This end-to-end encryption protocol
>   is designed to prevent third parties and WhatsApp from having plaintext
>   access to messages or calls.** What’s more, even if encryption keys
>   from a user’s device are ever physically compromised, they cannot be
>   used to go back in time to decrypt previously transmitted messages.

The last point refers to the property of *forward secrecy* which the Signal protocol provides by implementing the [double ratchet algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Ratchet_Algorithm). This means that even by compromising the current session, WhatsApp wouldn't be able to decrypt any past traffic - **there just is no *single* key** that could be used to "decrypt all your messages". So the claim make no sense considering how the protocol works.

That said - while the Signal protocol is open source, the WhatsApp client from your app store is not. If you distrust them to a degree that you expect WhatsApp to ship a backdoor routine in one of their updates, then you'll have to find an alternative messenger to trust.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not saying yes or no, but I'll explain some things and let you make up your own mind.

Whatsapp is closed source so they can publish whatever suits their needs, they don't have to disclose their secrets and surely won't.

Whatsapp claims to use end-to-end encryption and people will agree that end-to-end means that no one can read your messages. However, there's no full disclosure of how their protocol works or how end-to-end is implemented within the platform.

Take note, that if your device had an end encryption key and your device was wiped or lost there would be no way to recover your messages. However, with Whatsapp this is not the case, your messages can be backed up and restored on new devices, meaning that the keys and messages can be obtained by Whatsapp at any given time. Their protocol also controls the key exchange and can reseed your keys with as little as a phone number for identification. The app won't let you keep running without your sim, however, you can jmp or nope these basic checks and this allows you to run Whatsapp on multiple devices, so what good is end to end if they're just reseeding your keys anywhere.

Let's look at the reseed security of Whatsapp and why there's no alerts. To reseed all your messages on a new device all that's needed is your phone number. So think of any way you want to do this, there's lots. Port the number, swap the sim, clone the sim, buy the sim ikeys on darkweb, use sim virtualization..

Lastly, any company providing encryption services must still abide by encryption laws, so think truecrypt. If a supreme court demands Whatsapp to decrypt their messages, and just the same, if a supreme court demands Apple to decrypt a phone, they have a way to do it.

Whatsapp claims to exist to provide and support privacy. So why not truly be open sourced and transparent. What's to hide if you're just using xmpp and signal with a messaging gateway and some proprietary gateway.

What if I delete all my messages with no backup? Well that's assuming the other parties did it too, and that someone didn't spoof your phone number while you were sleeping and is now recording a copy of all messages. That Whatsapp didn't secretly link another device without telling you, and that if the messaging gateway was to undergo forensic analysis the messages couldn't be recovered or "undeleted".

Are your messages safe from sneaky eyes, competitors, ad bots, data mining, detectives, other apps, your ISP, your vpn, routerw, mitm network sniffers, and traffic analytics? For the most part, Yes, based on the context provided by Whatsapp.

Are your messages impossible to be seen by Whatsapp, the nsa or the fbi? Only if they aren't looking.

Comment: A bunch of logic errors, false equivalences, and some factual errors tossed in. Nothing in this answer supports the idea that they have a "golden key". At best, you've outline ways that, given the right circumstances, they might "hack" their way to access. But that's not the definition of a "golden key".